# how do I save info to a struct through a Linked List Node?

Tags: c

I want to save multiple customer infos into my struct customer, but need to access it through Node first but im not really sure how to write that. It would be reading info from a .in file.

```
typedef struct customer
{
  char *name;
  int items;
  int lineNumber;
  int timeEnter;
}customer;

typedef struct Node
{
    struct customer* customer;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;
```

My Idea was to use a for loop and iterate through it

```
  for(i = 0; i < amountCustomers; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", //TBA )
  }
```

But im not sure what to write for the TBA portion of the scanf. Thank you.

Comment: You need to allocate both the node and customer objects when building the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows -

```
//Considering you have Node *head somewhere declared and correctly allocated space.
for(i = 0; i < amountCustomers; i++)
{  
  scanf("%d", &(head->customer)->items );
  //scanf in similar way for other items
  head = head->next //moving to next node. 
}
```

Once you have defined your head node, you can other allocate and link other nodes together to make a link list or define a loop where you input into one node and keep adding it to your linked list.

If you have not defined Node *head, or not yet made the linked list, you can refer the following -

```
Node *head=NULL;       //declaring head pointer and making it Null
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    Node *new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)*sizeof(customer*)); //allocating space for new node
    new_node->next=NULL; //making next as Null
    new_node->customer = (customer*)malloc(sizeof(customer)) //allocating space for customer in new_node
    scanf("%d",&(new_node->customer)->items);
    //write scanf in similar way for other items
    printf("%d\n",new_node->customer->items);
    if(head==NULL){
        head = new_node;    //if no node is there in linked list, make new node to be the head
    }else{
        new_node->next=head; //else just point next of new node to head
        head = new_node ;     // and make it as head
    }
}
```

The above code will keep adding each new node to the beginning of linked list.

Hope this helps !

Comment: do I need to allocate the memory inside of the for loop? Or should I make the head outside first

Comment: @DingleBox I have made some edits. Check that . I would still recommend to write proper `add` and `init` methods for your linked list. There are many good guides online.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use linked list ?

```
typedef struct customer
{
  char *name;
  int items;
  int lineNumber;
  int timeEnter;
  customer* next;
}customer;
```